# I'm trying to make the bio for a website editable but I just can't get it

Tags: php, html, button, server, edit

So I'm making a website and I have a bio section on it. Then underneath is an edit button which sends you to a different page which pretty much looks the same except for some stuff is editable.

I have a part for when you click the save button that sends you back to the other page but it's commented out because it would just get stuck on the other page no matter if you clicked the edit button.The layout is all fine and you can you text in it and stuff, it just doesn't save the text and send you back correctly. Also, The bio only shows up blank now, even in my server, like it deletes all of the text.

```
<div class = "profileLeftSideContent" >
    <textarea rows="15" cols="40" name="bio" id="bio">
    <?php
$get_info = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT first_name, last_name, 
bio FROM users WHERE username = '$username'");
    $get_row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($get_info);
    $db_firstname = $get_row['first_name'];
    $db_last_name = $get_row['last_name'];
    $db_bio = $get_row['bio'];
    echo $db_bio;
    ?>
        </textarea>
</div>


<form method="post" class="budon" action="" onsubmit="return false">

<input type="submit" name="test" id="test" value="Save"/><br/>

</form>

<?php


    $get_info = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT first_name, 
last_name, bio FROM users WHERE username = '$username'");
    $get_row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($get_info);
    $db_firstname = $get_row['first_name'];
    $db_last_name = $get_row['last_name'];
    $db_bio = $get_row['bio'];
    $clided = "false";

    $bio = @$_POST['bio'];

$clunk = "true";

function click(){

    $clided = "true";



}
if($clided){

        //header("Location: profile.php ");

    $info_submit_query = mysqli_query($connection, "UPDATE users 
SET bio='$bio' WHERE username = '$username'");
    $clided = "false";




}   

if(array_key_exists('test',$_POST)){
   click();
    }
?>

Here is u: $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_GET['u']);


This is what click() does: function click(){

                 $clided = "true";      
             }
if($clided){

        //header("Location: profile.php ");

    $info_submit_query = mysqli_query($connection, "UPDATE users SET 
  bio='$bio' WHERE username = '$username'");
    $clided = "false";




}
```

I want the user to type in the text box, hit save, then get sent back to the other page with the new bio in the database.

Comment: `$username` is never set. You also are open to SQL injections. Parameterize. What are you doing with `click` also? `$clided` is local and never used.

Comment: Yah there is some stuff I didn't include in this code but I've pretty much done most of that.   if(isset($_GET['u'])){
 $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_GET['u']);
 if(ctype_alnum($username)){
  $check = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT username, first_name FROM users WHERE username = '$username'");
  if(mysqli_num_rows($check)===1){
   $get = mysqli_fetch_assoc($check);
   $username = $get['username'];
   $firstname = $get['first_name'];
  }         this is where I define $username

Comment: Where do you set `u`? Your `<textarea rows="15" cols="40" name="bio" id="bio">` is not in a `form`.

Comment: Please don't post code in the comments, instead edit your question and paste it there, thx. Also, what is your function `click()` supposed to do?

Comment: @kerbholz Okay ,I put the things in the code spot.

Comment: As @user3783243 stated, your `function click()` doesn't do anything. `$clided` is set inside the function scope and nothing is done with its value afterwards. Outside of the function `$clided` will _not_ be set to true when you call `click()`.